# Sprite Kit - how do I access child nodes function/IVARs?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working with tile map using Tiled.  I have an object on my map for the player spawn point.

I have been able to spawn the player object.  However, I'm at a loss as to how to access the player objects functions or IVARs??

In MyScene:

```
TileMapLayer *_playerLayer = [[TmxTileMapLayer alloc]
                initWithTmxObjectGroup:[_tileMap groupNamed:@"Spawn"]
                tileSize:_tileMap.tileSize
                gridSize:_bgLayer.gridSize
                objectType:@"Player"];
[_worldNode addChild:_playerLayer];
```

This will create a player object.  The player object has functions that I want to run and IVARs I want to query.  Note, some of the functions return values.

Example from the Player object:

```
- (BOOL)currentWeaponStatus
{
    return _weapon.hidden;
}
```

So far I think I can access it using:

```
BOOL weaponHidden = [[_playerLayer childNodeWithName:@"person"] childNodeWithName:@"weapon"].hidden;
```

But this doesn't seem 'simple'.  How do I access the child nodes' functions/IVARs in the _playerLayer?

FYI: I have a weapon node on the player node - this gets added to the tile map layer node.

Thanks for your time.
-Shoes

Comment: FYI: I did try: Person *player = [_playerLayer childNodeWithName:@"person"]; but received the warning: /.../MyScene.m:190:18: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Person *' with an expression of type 'SKNode *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I needed:

```
Person *player = (Person *)[_playerLayer childNodeWithName:@"person"];
```

Thanks to the Chris at Ray Wenderlich...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=11775&p=61090#p61090